# How to build JRuby 1.7.13 on Raspberry Pi with rbenv/ruby-build?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, jruby

I am trying to install JRuby (preferably version 1.7.13) onto a Raspberry Pi. I have rbenv/ruby-build installed. When I try to install JRuby (both 1.7.13 or 1.7.11), I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ rbenv install jruby-1.7.13
Downloading jruby-bin-1.7.13.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/faa1cd590f32f3cb92044d9abedf66ccea1d93a24236c877810c9b30e1e0577c
Installing jruby-1.7.13...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140713094726.2669
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140713094726.2669.log

Last 10 log lines:
jruby-1.7.13/tool/nailgun/Makefile.in
jruby-1.7.13/tool/nailgun/ng.exe
jruby-1.7.13/tool/nailgun/README.txt
jruby-1.7.13/tool/nailgun/src/c/ng.c
/tmp/ruby-build.20140713094726.2669/jruby-1.7.13 /tmp/ruby-build.20140713094726.2669 ~
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    Could not load FFI Provider: (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: null
 See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Is it possible to build JFFI for Linux on ARM and how would should I go about doing that?

Comment: Have you tried RVM as well (if it fails the same) ?

Comment: No not yet. As I understand, I'd need to remove rbenv before doing that. I may try to compile from the source.

Comment: than, make sure to try the **jruby-1_7** branch (as well) ... also any reason why you want to build that yourself instead of using the binary (it won't make any big difference) ? I would try 1.7.12 with **rbenv** (never actually used it) than "degrade" to RVM or simply download and unpack the .zip distribution ... unless you're really into switching Rubies on 3.14 :)

Comment: I have already tried to install JRuby 1.7.11 with rbenv and got a similar result. The reason that I'm going to try to install from "source" is to see if I can compile JFFI before the installation.

I'm not worried about switching versions or Gemsets with JRuby. The reason that I want to install it is to see if I can get Shoes 4 working on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is possibly that some of the difficulties I have faced are due to memory problems. My Raspberry Pi is a Model A, the local (country) distributor doesn't expect any more Model Bs until December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is to compile JFFI on the Raspberry Pi and copy the generated libjffi-1.2.so to /usr/lib. When I now try to install JRuby 1.7.13 using rbenv, I no longer get the missing FFI error but "Cannot allocate memory" errors.

The procedure I followed to compile libjffi was;

```
cd ~
pi@raspberrypi:~$ git clone git://github.com/jnr/jffi.git jffi.git
cd jffi.git
ant jar
sudo cp libjffi-1.2.so /usr/lib
```